# How do i draw rectangle blocks on resized image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr

I have certain images from which i want to identify the text blocks and draw rectangle around them, but these images are of varying dimensions so, I have resized them to a new dimension and I am able to draw blocks around the text. But afterwards i have to apply OCR on these blocks and when I resized the image to a lower dimension these blocks texts got blurry.

Example: After resizing the image of dimensions (5847, 4134) to (1000,700)
I was able to draw the text blocks but after getting the co-ordinates of these blocks even if i multiply by the ratio of the image resized it is not showing exact blocks like this:

Blocks After resizing 
[image]

Drawing blocks over original image with co-ordinates from resized image
[image]

to draw the blocks on original i have done something like this:

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    x = round(x*x_old/wid)
    y = round(y*y_old/hei)
    w = round(w*x_old/wid)
    h = round(h*y_old/hei)
```

where x_old is original height in this case 5874, y_old is 4134, wid is 1000 and hei is 700

Comment: in your code rather assigning new values to x,y,w,h try adding these new calculated values to previous one like x += round()

Comment: I think your width and height are swapped somehow. Can you share all of your code? It makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @AnandCU thanks for your help. Yes, the x_old and y_old were swapped but still it wasn't that accurate so i moved the round function to the internal division which fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an geometry problem than a Opencv one.

Let's say you know all the rectangles for a image that has a 1000X1000 dimension, and let's imagine that the rectangles are `rec1 = ([0,0],[100,100])` and `rec2 = ([50,50],[90,90])` being `([y1,x1],[y2,x2])`.

Ok, now let's imagine that you have another image whith shape 1255X1300 and you want to draw the same rectangles in this new image relatively to the old one.

What you have to do is find the x and y ratios between the two images and apply those ratios to the images. Or you could express your rectangle in a relative manner.

**Calculate Ratio:**

To calculate the ratio between the two images, just divide its x and y dimensions:

```
x_ratio = x_new/x_old
y_ratio = y_new/y_old
```

In our case it would be:

> x_ratio = 1.300
>   y_ratio = 1.255

Now you apply this ratios to the rectangles and round its values. You just multiply the rectangle's x by the x_ratio and the rectangle's y by the y_ratio and round the vales (keep in mind that rounding makes it lose a little bit of precision)

**Relative Rectangles:**

You can also represent the rectangles relatively to the first image by dividing its corresponding dimensions. The relative rectangles should look like this: `rel_rec1 = ([0.,0.],[0.1,0.1])`, `rel_rec2 = ([0.05,0.05],[0.09,0.09])`

Then, to know the absolute values of rectangles in the new image, you just need to multiply the relative rectangles to the new image's dimensions and round the values, for example

```
new_rec2 = ([0.05*1255,0.05*1300],[0.09*1255,0.09*1300])
```

I hope it helped

Comment: yes this is exactly what i did, previously i was getting confused between  x and y ratio values. Now, i got it working and was about to write the answer here but thanks to you i don't have to anymore. Thank you for the detailed explanation.